# asp.net Membership/Role/Profile providers - Good or Bad?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

Recently a co-worker suggested that the use of the built-in MS Membership, Role and Profile providers is a bad idea. He didn't really explain in too much detail as to why, however, he did mention that the architecture is bad if you're working towards high volume sites. Wondering what the opinion of the community is on this?  Curious if it's best to roll your own or use the built in MS providers? What is the best practice in this arena?

Comment: You could [build a custom MemebrshipProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx) by inheriting from MembershipProvider or direct from f.e. SqlMembershipProvider. Not sure if your co-worker ment this. But i don't think that it's a good idea to reinvent the wheel completely.

Comment: I agree, the provider model is a robust a proven way to implement authentication in .NET, and in a way that increases interoperability. It has weak points which can be security hardened, but reinventing the wheel generally leads to insecure implementations using session or something terrible like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is question probably going to be closed as subjective and argumentative, but here are some links with good points and opinions from people smarter than me for you to consider and decide on your own:

1. http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/11/your-internet-drivers-license.html
2. Linked to from the above article but worth a link of its own: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/05/openid-does-the-world-really-need-yet-another-username-and-password.html
3. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication

I'm a strong believer in the Internet Drivers License concept myself.

Rolling your own is a bad idea unless you really don't have strong security requirements.  As a general rule of thumb, we web developers are bad at security.  The ASP.NET Membership tools were written by people who are good at security - people who work for a company that has an unfairly tarnished reputation (in my opinion) and have something to prove by getting it right.

However, if you have to choose between using the built-in providers, and rolling your own, I would argue against what your co-worker said.

Despite their bad rep, Microsoft is very concerned with security, as shown by the [wealth of information freely provided to developers on this subject alone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security).  I would put my trust in them before I would in my own abilities to come up with a secure system.

As for performance, I haven't had any negative expierence with the built-in provider, but I don't think the sites I'm working with are particularly high volume (only around 10,000 hits per day).

Final edit -

If you do go with the built-in provider, the OWASP website has info on the recommended settings: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Reviewing_Code_for_Authentication

Comment: I am confused what openid has to do with the asp.net providers the OP mentions. Also not sure what authentication has to do with the provider the OP mentions... don't believe he is talking about rolling his own authentication / authorization. Just whether the cookie cutter providers are ok. Personally, I hate the Membership Provider implementation and don't see the point of creating a custom Membership provider...

Comment: @B Z - I understand not wanting to use the providers.  However, answering your comment, If you look at the last sentence in his question, it does say "Curious if it's best to roll your own or use the built in MS providers?" which is why I went into such detail on why NOT to roll your own.  The OpenId was thrown in as an alternative because there are more than just two options for him to consider.  Also, Jeff Atwood makes a very good point in those articles about the problem of every developer on earth coming up with their own mechanism and standards.

Comment: Thanks guys... great input... exactly what i was looking for. Specifically high volume sites were the main area and openId could help out there.  Also, I did find a aps.net provider wrapper for OpenID - maybe this is a good way to get the best of both worlds!

Answer (score 1):

<opinion>

my experience with the built in provider is that it works...sometimes... The problem with a few of the projects I did was that it didn't offer as much customization as we wanted or what customization it did offer was so much work we rolled our own anyway. Granted, I'm a n00b at programming next to some.

So it really comes down to what you want. Will the MS SQL Provider work and do what you want out of the box? Great! Use that. Other wise, I'd say do it yourself.

</opinion>

Answer (score 1):

The main issue levelled at the Provider model is that it hails from the ASP.NET 2.0 web forms era where testability had much lower precedence than making components easy to use. The Provider model encourages the use of static classes and static methods to make things work, making it potentially difficult to test and this is baked in to the authentication and authorisation mechanisms of the platform e.g. `Membership.GetUser()` and its use of `IIdentity.Name` and `RolePrincipal` and its use of the `Roles.IsUserInRole(string role)` being two prime examples. What's more, one needs to go to some lengths to coerce them into working with patterns like Inversion of Control and Dependency Injection because of how the instances are instantiated and controlled by the framework. This can lead people to rolling their own solutions.

All that said, the providers are a tried and trusted approach to solid authentication and authorisation in ASP.NET applications. If you know what you're doing you can do without them, but if you don't, either take the time to understand how they work and how you can provide the similar functionality more flexibly in your system or just use them until they become a problem.

Comment: I would never write code with a dependency on Membership, it's not true that there is a reliance on these static methods, they are just shortcuts to the provider instance. Instead I would use DI to inject MembershipProvider which can be Mocked, likewise IPrinciple and IIdentity are highly testable.

Comment: Reliance is not the right word, but they are the road most travelled to get at the instances, much like `HttpContext.Current` is used to get the current context outside of the pipeline (even if injected via a container facility method). Using DI to inject a provider requires registration of a provider to delegate to the container provided one. My point is, someone like yourself with numerous years experience has the skills and knowledge to build a loosely coupled and highly cohesive system and work around taking direct dependencies on hard to test code and...

Comment: you probably also have the skills and knowledge to roll your own membership and roles implementation, but not everyone does. Therefore use the providers unless you **really know** what you're doing.

Comment: True but implementing providers is a case of implementing an abstract class. There's a lot more hand holding with this than someone who doesn't know what they are doing rolling their own authentication. I don't think discouraging the right way of doing something because of skill is sensible.

Comment: I don't feel like I was discouraging their use, I was trying to give a balanced answer on their pros and cons. Are they the right way? They're the framework way, but does that make them a good or the best way? To me, it means they're provided for you if you want to use them and should unless they don't fit your needs well.

Comment: Both of these views make sense as well. In fact they're sorta riding the same path. I think I can inherit from the providers to create a custom provider in which I can handle whatever specifics I need. I can always avoid using the M$ structure and just map appropriate data to the method params in the provider classes...

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Membership, Role and Profile model to write custom providers that suit my needs, and many others have done the same. You are not locked in to the Provider model. You need to do the research, determine if it meets your needs, and make appropriate decisions. You now have offerings such as OpenId and the newer BrowserID that can easily be integrated with Microsoft's provider model to accomplish your goals. Nobody is holding a gun to your head. Get the facts, do some research, and decide what's right for you. If you want to see some good examples of what others have done, do a search on codeplex.com where there are a number of different offerings.

Comment: This is true... I can do whatever I want under the hood so long as the method calls match - figured that out after downloading the RavenDB Membership provider. Great example! And thanksf or the tip!